# Bitbucket repo access for several users

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I have a git repository in a server that belongs to a client.

That repository is hosted at bitbucket, and it is part of a team for which I am an administrator.

What I need to be able to do is to configure the remote origin with the team url, so that I can go to the server, type `git push`, and insert my username and password.

Afterwards, if the server admin goes to the server and makes a change to that repo, he should be able to do 'git push' and insert his username and password, without having to change the remote origin repo location.

Is this possible? One team repo URL, and ability to push changes with different users.

With the configuration I use normally, I am only asked for my password, as the repo URL already has my username builtin, and I only need to insert my password. The thing is that I do not want to share my password, and the client does not want to keep changing the remote origin url.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the username from the repository URL then Git will use the username of the logged user to push to Bitbucket. Use the "git remote set-url" to do this:

```
> git remote set-url origin https://BITBUCKET-SERVER/REPOSITORY
```

Another alternative is to have two different remotes, one for you and another for the client. Use the "git remote add" to do this:

```
> git remote add YOUR-REMOTE-NAME https://YOUR-USER@BITBUCKET-SERVER/REPOSITORY

> git remote add CLIENT-REMOTE-NAME https://CLIENT-USER@BITBUCKET-SERVER/REPOSITORY
```

To push using the correct user execute:

```
> git push YOUR-REMOTE-NAME

or

> git push CLIENT-REMOTE-NAME
```

instead of "git push"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Marcelo. That is actually the option I know, but I would like to have only one origin, that origin being a team instead of a user, and then when the push was made, the credentials were added. Something such as git remote add origin https://team@BITBUCKET-SERVER/REPOSITORY and then, when I git push, I would be asked my user and pass, and when the client does git push, we would input his user and pass.

Comment: Does everybody involved with this use the same username in the computer? This is really not recommended.

Comment: no, the objective is to use different usernames. My client told me that it is possible to do that using a single team origin URL, and when you push you are asked for user and pass.

Comment: So... why you do not just remove the user part of the repository URL?

Comment: you can do that? I had no idea... I will try to do that.

Comment: Hello Marcelo I just tried this and it does not seem to work. I have this as the origin `https://@BITBUCKET-SERVER/REPOSITORY` (actually I have two origins, this is one of them) and I only get asked the password, not the username, so it fails.

Comment: Sorry, you need to take the "@" off. I updated my answer. Git will not ask for your username, it will use the username you're logged in.